# How to resolve error Implicit conversion of int to uitextfield is disallowed while migrating to ARC?

Tags: iphone, memory-management, automatic-ref-counting

I am getting error while converting my app to ARC.The error is :Implicit conversion of int to UItextfield is disallowed with ARC.How to cast them using toll free bridging?-

```
-(void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    //if (![textField isEqual:normal]) {
    if (textField == numberKeyPad.currentTextField) {

        [self.numberKeyPad removeButtonFromKeyboard];

    }

    if (numberKeyPad.currentTextField ==normal) 
    {

        [self.numberKeyPad removeButtonFromKeyboard];

    }
}
```

I am getting the error for if (numberKeyPad.currentTextField ==normal) line.How to resolve it?

Comment: oops.  Looks like the code is attempting to compare an int ("normal") with a UITextField ("currentTextField"), though it's hard to tell from the code snippet provided - since neither is declared in this scope. Perhaps you meant to compare 'normal' against some integer value, which would be a fine thing to do.  Comparing it against a UITextField, is not.  Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are comparing object (`UITextField`) with primitive type (`int`). Because of that compiler is throwing an error.
Try this -

```
-(void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    //if (![textField isEqual:normal]) {
    if (textField == numberKeyPad.currentTextField) {

        [self.numberKeyPad removeButtonFromKeyboard];

    }

    if ([((numberKeyPad.currentTextField).text) intValue] ==normal) 
    {

        [self.numberKeyPad removeButtonFromKeyboard];

    }
}
```